# binary integer to integer array in c

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I have an variable `unsigned int x = 0b0011` how can I make it to unsigned integer array, like `y[0]=0 ; y[1]=0; y[2]=1; y[3]=1;` ?

Comment: Is this an int `0b0011`?

Comment: Do you always know the number of bits in the binary representation or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Noor: I can define the variable as 'int' if it is necessary. @Jordan Kaye: I just need to output binary values from a GPIO, I need to know the integer value as binaries. So I can say it is not arbitrary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shifting and bitwise operations.

```
unsigned x = 0b0011; // yap this is a GNU extension, it doesn't always work even with GCC

const size_t intsize = sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; // go go indepency-of-sizeof(int)!

unsigned bits[intsize]; // that's why we love constexprs

int i, j;
for (i = intsize - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) { // and the comma operator too
    bits[j] = (x >> i) & 0x1;
}
```